# highlight a row in a table (html)

Tags: php, html, css

I have a simple webpage.
I'm generating a table from a SQL query and trying to highlight a row (change background colour to yellow for that row) for some rows.

This is my current table:

```
 <table class="tftable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>No_</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Aanbest datum</th>
        <th>Aanbest uur</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Bouwheer</th>
        <th>Werf adres</th>
        <th>Klasse</th>
        <th>Calculator</th>
        <th>Plaatsbezoek</th>
        <th>Status</th>
<?php 
    while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
?>        
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['No_']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Job Type Code']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 8']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 9']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Site Address'] .", " . $rows['Site Postcode'] . " " . $rows['Site City']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 5']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Salesperson Code']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 6']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Internal Status']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php     
    }
?>    
</table>
```

Each row contains a Date field. I would like to compare that date with the current date, if equal then highlight, if not nothing happens.

UPDATE: see image that proposed solution only updates the Date field
[image]

Comment: You said you're trying. So what did you try? What went wrong? What did you research? I see no evidence here of any attempt. Where are you stuck exactly? You don't know how to compare dates? It's not hard to Google it. Or you don't know how to make a Html element have a different background colour? Again it's not hard to Google that either. It's unclear what the actual difficulty is here. We like to help people here, but we appreciate it if they show that they at least tried to help themselves first before asking for others to do it for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your date is `Custom Field 8`:
Replace this:

```
<td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 8']; ?></td>
```

With:

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d', time());
if ($rows['Custom Field 8']==$date) {
    echo "<td style='color:red'>" . $rows['Custom Field 8'] . "</td>";
} else {
    echo "<td>" .  $rows['Custom Field 8'] . "</td>";
}
?>
```

It gets current date, converts into SQL date format (you can use dat-time same way by adding h:i to PHP date) and compare it to your output.
If you store your date in DB like text, just change the format in first row to match yours.

To apply on whole row replace your opening `<tr>` tag with:

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d', time());
if ($rows['Custom Field 8']==$date) {
    echo "<tr style='color:red'>";
} else {
    echo "<tr>";
}
?>
```

Style it inline or load with new CSS class.

Comment: Doing this still only highlights the Date field, not the whole row

Comment: update: i have uploaded a image to show you

Comment: @IvanPudic Then apply same method for your tr tag, ill update my code in sec.

Comment: Thank you so much, easy, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, I am not sure which data item the 'date' is so I have just used date,

```
<table class="tftable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>No_</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Aanbest datum</th>
        <th>Aanbest uur</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Bouwheer</th>
        <th>Werf adres</th>
        <th>Klasse</th>
        <th>Calculator</th>
        <th>Plaatsbezoek</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <?php
        while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        ?>
    <tr <?php echo $rows['date'] == date("Y-m-d") ? 'style="background-color:yellow;"' : ''; ?>>
        <td><?php echo $rows['No_']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Job Type Code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 8']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 9']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Description']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Site Address'] .", " . $rows['Site Postcode'] . " " . $rows['Site City']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 5']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Salesperson Code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Custom Field 6']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Internal Status']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['date']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: this only highlights the field Date, does not highlight the whole row

Comment: @IvanPudic Good point, answer updated.